# Tab View wont show up in activity?

Tags: android

As the title says, I'm trying to set up this TabView in my app and every time I go to run that activity, Just a black screen?
I've looked up a few tutorials and still no luck, here's what I have in my activity..

```
protected void onCreate(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabView);
    TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup();

    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    TabSpec tabSpec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag1");
    tabSpec1.setContent(R.id.Tab1);
    tabSpec1.setIndicator("Tab1");
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec1); 

    TabSpec tabSpec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag2");
    tabSpec2.setContent(R.id.Tab2);
    tabSpec2.setIndicator("Tab2");
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec2);

    TabSpec tabSpec3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag3");
    tabSpec3.setContent(R.id.Tab3);
    tabSpec3.setIndicator("Tab3");
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are adding Tabs to the activity screen or the actionBar. But if it's the former, something like this will help:

```
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1")
                .setIndicator("tab1", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.stat_happy))
                .setContent(this));
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2")
                .setIndicator("tab2", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.stat_neutral))
                .setContent(this));
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3")
                .setIndicator("tab3", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.stat_sad))
                .setContent(this));

    }

    @Override
    public View createTabContent(String tag) {
        final TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Content for tab with tag " + tag);
        return tv;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to add tabs to the Tabhost

Comment: Then the above code should work. I have extended TabActivity but in your case you don't have to. I am implementing TabContentFactory and hence have createTabContent method to create views for each tab. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

To add tabs in action bar, you need to set the navigation mode first `bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);` to your action bar and then add tabs.

Check this [sample](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html#actionbar_navigation_tab) tutorial.

Comment: Now you are adding tabs to the tabhost. However, you can also add tabs to action bar. If you need this approach, you need to add tabs to actionbar using actionBar.addTab() function.